# create dynamically menu and submenu from database in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I want to display menu dynamically from database. But My menu items are displaying but when i used to click on menu,submenu is not displaying.please tell me where is the error

My code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { GetMenuData(); }
}
private void GetMenuData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ST015\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=True");
    string sql = "select menuId,Menuname,MenuDescription,ParentMenuid,MenuUrl from Categories";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(table);
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    view.RowFilter = "ParentMenuId is NULL";
    foreach (DataRowView row in view)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(row["MenuName"].ToString(),
            row["MenuId"].ToString());
        menuItem.NavigateUrl = row["MenuUrl"].ToString();
        Menu1.Items.Add(menuItem);
        AddChildItems(table, menuItem);
    }
}
private void AddChildItems(DataTable table, MenuItem menuItem)
{
    DataView viewItem = new DataView(table);
    viewItem.RowFilter = "ParentMenuId=" + menuItem.Value;
    foreach (DataRowView childView in viewItem)
    {
        MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem(childView["MenuName"].ToString(),
            childView["MenuId"].ToString());
        childItem.NavigateUrl = childView["MenuUrl"].ToString();
        menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
        AddChildItems(table, childItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to remove isPostBack's check, it will work fine...

Comment: I have removed but still the same output is displaying

Comment: can you please run the code i have pasted in answer.. i have already implemented this code in many projects.. you can try this one..

Comment: i could not understand the stored procedure please explain me properly

Answer (score 1):

I think when you are clicking on the menu items , it is causing the page to `PostBack`  and you are creating the menus when the page is loading for the first time.Hence you are unable to see the menu on click of menu items.Just call the `GetMenuData();` method on page load without checking for `IsPostBack` property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GetMenuData(); 
}
```

Comment: still the submenu is not populating. Please tell me the solution why it is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for menu's

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMenuMaster](
[MenuID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MenuName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[DisplayOrder] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[MenuID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Create another table for sub menu's

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSubMenuMaster](
[SubMenuID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MenuID] [int] NULL,
[SubMenuName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[MainMenuDisplayOrder] [int] NULL,
[DisplayOrder] [int] NULL,
[SubMenuUrl] [varchar](500) NULL,
[VisibleInMenu] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SubMenuID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now go to master page .. 
HTML code is:

```
   <div class="menubar">
        <%--<ul class="tabs">--%>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltMenus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <%--</ul>--%>
    </div>
```

Code behind code is :

```
private void GenerateMenus()
{
    clsMenu obj = new clsMenu();
    System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    String PageName = "";
    PageName = Path.GetFileName(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath);
    ds = obj.GetMenusByRole(GetRoleId(), PageName);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<ul class='tabs'>");

    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("<li class='{0}'><a rel='{1}' href='{1}' > {2} </a> ", Convert.ToString(row["css"]), ResolveUrl(Convert.ToString(row["PagePath"])), Convert.ToString(row["MenuName"])));
        //sb.Append(String.Format("<li '><a rel='{0}' href='{0}' > {1} </a> ", ResolveUrl(Convert.ToString(row["PagePath"])), Convert.ToString(row["MenuName"])));

        System.Data.DataTable t = CCMMUtility.GetFilterDataforIntColumn("MenuID", Convert.ToString(row["MenuID"]), ds.Tables[1]);
        if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append("<ul>");

            for (int i = 0; i < t.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("<li><a href='{0}' class='dir' style='cursor: pointer;'>{1}</a></li>", ResolveUrl(Convert.ToString(t.Rows[i]["PagePath"])), Convert.ToString(t.Rows[i]["PageAliasName"])));
            }

            sb.Append("</ul>");
        }
        sb.Append("</li>");
    }

    sb.Append("</ul>");


    ltMenus.Text = sb.ToString();

}
```

it needs stored proc to call menu's dynamic according to Role id like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetMenusByRole]
(
@RoleId int,  
@PageName varchar(100)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT mm.MenuID, mm.MenuName,dbo.Extract_CssNameForMenuByMenuIDAndPageName(mm.MenuID, @PageName) as css
,dbo.proc_Extract_MenuPageByRoleIDAndMenuID(@RoleId, mm.MenuID)
as PagePath , mm.DisplayOrder   FROM tblMenuMaster mm WHERE mm.MenuID IN (SELECT s.MenuID from tblSiteRolePermissions p INNER JOIN
tblSitePages s ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
WHERE (p.fkRoleId = @RoleId and p.ViewOnly=1))   
Union All   
select 0 as menuid ,'Change Password' as MenuName,  
case @pagename   
when 'ChangePassword.aspx' then 'active'  
else ''  
end  as css,'~/User/ChangePassword.aspx' as PagePath, 10000 as Displayorder  
ORDER BY DisplayOrder     
SELECT s.MenuID, s.pkSitePageId, s.PageAliasName, s.SitePageName,s.pagepath from tblSiteRolePermissions p 
INNER JOIN tblSitePages s ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId  WHERE (p.fkRoleId =@RoleId and p.ViewOnly=1) ORDER BY s.pkSitePageId
```

//new sp starts here

```
CREATE function [dbo].[Extract_CssNameForMenuByMenuIDAndPageName](@MenuID int, 
PageName varchar(100))
returns nvarchar(50)
as begin      
declare @result nvarchar(50) 
set @result = ''    
IF EXISTS (SELECT pkSitePageId FROM tblsitepages WHERE (MenuID = @MenuID) AND (UPPER(SitePageName) = @PageName)) 
 BEGIN    
  SET @result = 'active'    
 END    
return @result    
end
```

// another sp used is

```
CREATE function [dbo].[proc_Extract_MenuPageByRoleIDAndMenuID]
(@RoleId int, @MenuID int)
returns nvarchar(500) 
as begin          
declare @result nvarchar(500)
SELECT top 1 @result = s.pagepath FROM tblSitePages AS s INNER JOIN tblSiteRolePermissions AS p ON s.pkSitePageId = p.fkSitePageId
WHERE (p.fkRoleId = @RoleId) AND (s.MenuID = @MenuID)  and p.ViewOnly=1
ORDER BY s.pkSitePageId 
return  @result
end
```

Its just a way to do this you can modify this according to your requirement.........

**proc_Extract_MenuPageByRoleIDAndMenuID** sp is used to get  Page name and its path,

**Extract_CssNameForMenuByMenuIDAndPageName** sp is used to set **active** class to the first **li** means first menu. 
Hop this will help you..... 
Its the working code..

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code it is working well may be possible there is error in your data which you are adding to menu.May be "ParentMenuid" is missing or may be wrong